# Disable Plank Mouse Hover Tooltips

Tags: plank

Is there any way to disable launcher mouse hover tooltips in Plank ? I would really like to achieve this. Adding the line gtk-enable-tooltips = 0 to my .gtkrc-2.0 file in my home folder doesn't disable hover tips in Plank. I'm on Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

`gtk-enable-tooltips = 0` in a `.gtkrc-2.0` file doesn't work anymore, I'm on Xubuntu 16.04.

Plank seems like not much more than a panel launcher and window button integrated into one application, so why not the simple option to disable tooltips just the same as in a standard Xfce launcher, under **properties** > **advanced**, check the box for **"disable tooltips"** for each launcher ?

Comment: I agree. I added a lot of blank icon (because plank doesnt have a separator) so now I have a lot of blank tooltip popping up all the time i move the mouse over them. :D